# Telerik grid EditForm Popup Events Issue

Tags: ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

I implemented telerik grid with add / update options using popup editform templete. Every thing was working fine    without ajax and when i enabled ajax popup form events are not firing properly. I have defined CommandName and on server end i implemented ItemCommand event. If i apply breakpoint on all events of form then after clicking on popup button only Load method of form is called and nothing else happens. Please help following is my Client end code

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gridMain" runat="server"  EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Skin="MpoGrayGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" OnItemDataBound="gridMain_ItemDataBound" OnNeedDataSource="gridMain_NeedDataSource" OnItemCommand="gridMain_ItemCommand">
                            <MasterTableView EditMode="PopUp" CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="EEHireTermID">
                            <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>
                            <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column"></RowIndicatorColumn>
                            <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Created="True"></ExpandCollapseColumn>
                                <Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Employee">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Type">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblType"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="ActionDate">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblActionDate"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Entered Date">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEnteredDate"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Entered By">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEnteredBy"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Reason  For Termination">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTermReason"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Memo">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMemo"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Action">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" CausesValidation="False" Text="Edit" CssClass="Link2" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CausesValidation="False" Text="Delete" CssClass="Link2" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <EditFormSettings InsertCaption="Add Hire/Termination Dates" CaptionFormatString="Add Hire/Termination Dates" 
                                    CaptionDataField="Id" EditFormType="Template" PopUpSettings-Modal="true" PopUpSettings-Width="663">
<EditColumn InsertImageUrl="Update.gif" UpdateImageUrl="Update.gif" CancelImageUrl="Cancel.gif" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
                                    <FormTemplate>
                                        <table id="tblEdit" runat="server" width="663" style="margin: 24px; border-radius: 20px;" cellpadding="6" >

                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="1" class="BodyText" width="31%" >Employee: </td>
                                                <td colspan="1" width="69%">
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="TextField1" ID="txtName" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="1" class="BodyText" width="31%">Type:</td>
                                                <td colspan="1"  width="69%">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlType" CssClass="DropDown1" onchange="changeType(this)">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="H">Hire</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="T">Termination</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="E">PEO</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="N">PEO Termination</asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvReq1" runat="server" CssClass="Heading1" ControlToValidate="ddlType" ErrorMessage="* Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="1" class="BodyText" width="31%">Action/EffectiveDate:</td>
                                                <td colspan="1"  width="69%">
                                                    <telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdpActionDate"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                                    &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvReq2" runat="server" CssClass="Heading1" ControlToValidate="rdpActionDate" ErrorMessage="* Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="1" class="BodyText" width="31%">Reason For Termination:</td>
                                                <td colspan="1"  width="69%">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTermReason" CssClass="DropDown1">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvReq3" CssClass="Heading1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlTermReason" ErrorMessage="* Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="BodyText" width="31%">Memo:</td>
                                                <td  width="69%">
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMemo" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="86px" Width="346px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="txtSave" CommandName="Update" CssClass="Buttons" Text="Save" />&nbsp;
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnCancel" CssClass="Link_Cancel" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </FormTemplate>

                            <PopUpSettings Modal="True" Width="663px" >

                            </PopUpSettings>
                                </EditFormSettings>

                            <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox"></PagerStyle>
                                <CommandItemTemplate>
                                    <table width="100%"  cellpadding="10">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" CommandName="InitInsert"  Text="Add New Record" CssClass="Buttons" /></td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Export" ID="lbtnExport" Text="Export"><img src="../images/excel.jpg"/> Export</asp:LinkButton></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </CommandItemTemplate>
                            </MasterTableView>
                             <ClientSettings>
                                <ClientEvents OnPopUpShowing="PopUpShowing" />
                              </ClientSettings>

                                    <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox"></PagerStyle>
                                    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"></FilterMenu>
                                    <HeaderContextMenu EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"></HeaderContextMenu>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many days to fix the issue, i found out the cause of issue. I used System.Compression to compress and decompress the view state. I think Telerik has some issue with it thats why it stopped working. When commented this code in my BasePage it started working properly

Comment: Yep. You need to use the Telerik RadCompression module to compress the viewstate if you're using Telerik controls.

Answer (score 1):

I've copied your code into a new webform with `AutoEventWireup="true"` configured and I am seeing all 3 events fire: ItemDataBound, NeedDataSource, and the ItemCommand when I click your Edit button.

If you do not want to use AutoEventWireup, you will need to connect the events of the Grid to their event handlers appropriately in CreateChildControls or earlier in the page's lifecycle.

Comment: Clicks on grid are fired correctly, but issue is with popup screen. If click save / cancel on popup screen no event is triggered except form load